# Can I combine a LINQ and a foreach that I use to add objects to a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following code:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectiveDetail> toBeAdded = 
   objectiveDetail1.Where(a => objectiveDetail2.All(
                          b => b.ObjectiveDetailId != a.ObjectiveDetailId));
```

Then:

```
foreach (var _obj in toBeAdded)
{
   _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(_obj);
}
```

This works and adds the one (or many) new object details to the collection.

However I am wondering. Is there another way that I could do this that would combine the LINQ and the foreach?

Comment: your first snippet could have been much simpler with a except.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

Comment: You should not try to replace a `foreach` with Linq since they are orthogonal concepts. The `foreach` is the cheapest way to execute a linq query since it doesn't need to create a new collection(like `ToList`). It is used to _consume_ the result. A linq query on the other hand _produces_ the result, it is a query that should not have side-effects and should not modify collections. Therefore the `foreach` is the best way.

Comment: Yeah there is another way. Learn how to use collections and navigation properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do this way -

```
objectiveDetail1.Where(a => objectiveDetail2.All(
                       b => b.ObjectiveDetailId != a.ObjectiveDetailId))
                      .ToList().ForEach(_uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add);
```

Comment: That is O(2n) for absolutely no reason. You're enumerating over the sequence to make it a list and then ForEaching over it?

Comment: Yeah, OP asked for clubbing two operations into one. So, i just give him the way. I agree that it can be optimized using `Except` and `AddRange`.

Comment: @ It'sNotALie good point ,but for someone who is not very well versed in linq,this answer is easier to understand.

Comment: I am not sure AddRange would work here. My ObjectiveDetails has methods for Add, Update and Delete only.

Comment: Why do you create another collection with `ToList()`? This is really, really inefficient, both in terms of CPU and memory consumption. For every object it needs to check all objects of the other collection, then you create the fourth collection(which could already cause an `OutOfMemoryException)`, just to be able to use `List.ForEach` what is absolutely redundant here.

Answer (score 3):

So you actually want to add all objects which are not in the second collection. [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is much more efficient(assuming the `ObjectiveDetailId` is unique):

```
IEnumerable<ObjectiveDetail> toBeAdded = objectiveDetail1.Except(objectiveDetail2);
```

You need to override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`:

```
public class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    // other properties ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var obj2 = obj as ObjectiveDetail;
        if (obj2 == null) return false;
        return ObjectiveDetailId == obj2.ObjectiveDetailId;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ObjectiveDetailId;
    }
}
```

Btw, you don't need the `foreach`, you can use   [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx):

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.AddRange(toBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest method would be

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.AddRange(toBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.AddRange(
    objectiveDetail1.Where(a => objectiveDetail2.All(
        b => b.ObjectiveDetailId != a.ObjectiveDetailId)));
```

Comment: "yep" isn't cool the way you think it is.  You should include a bit more context to explain how your solution addresses the question

Comment: @APC  He asked a "can you" question. The logical answer is yes or no.

Comment: Your answer got flagged as low quality.  But to be fair it's not much terser than several other answers in this thread, including the accepted one/

Comment: @APC That's because the low-qual filter doesn't take into account the question's quality.